# Visual Studio says file generators cannot be run until database model is resolved. Why?

Tags: visual-studio, t4, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

Sometimes when I try to run a T4 template inside a Sql Server project, I get this message:

[image]

I tried googling this and found no results at all.

What does that even means? And why does it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so it seems to appear only when VS is analysing the project's structure. When it's done the TT can run without this dialog showing up.

Comment: If the model is being built ssdt won't do much, there was a question here recently about create unit tests greyed out with a failed model it is all related to that.